# Loose TT Bar Pads

Tags: handlebars, carbon

I have Easton attack carbon TT bars which have pads that are riveted on. One has now come loose and is wobbly. I have tried to drill out and re-rivet them on but the problem comes back. Does anyone have experience with these?

Can I use some sort of self tapping screws into the carbon to hold them down or will this damage the carbon fiber? Thanks.

[image: TT Bars]

Comment: I would explore the possibility of using heat shrink on top.  Risks of the heat damaging the carbon are low but not zero, and you'd lose the pretty yellow colour.   Also check with Easton's customer support - its possible these are a known issue and there is a specific fix.

Answer (score 1):

Self-tapping screws are more likely to destroy the bars than fix anything

If you mean the forearm/elbow rests which attach either side of the stem, you could consider bonding the bracket to the bar with a suitable epoxy adhesive (vibration resistance being one consideration), in conjunction with re-riveting to give access and stability.

The right adhesive and applicator however could get quite expensive and you might prefer to put the cash towards replacement bars if you have no success with customer support.